# Performance monitoring tools vs the process status (ps) command

Tags: python, bash, performance, performance-testing

I am currently in the lookout for performance monitoring tools, tools which produce an output of metrics of specific OS processes. I want something which is lightweight (not to effect the performance of the system it is currently monitoring), hence I wrote a simple bash script which uses the `ps` command to retrieve CPU% and Memory%, writes them to a file, and sleeps for a specified couple of seconds, and repeats until it is terminated.

The question I have is whether this is a correct approach because as found on the documentation of `ps` ([here](https://ss64.com/osx/ps.html)):

> Since ps cannot run faster than the system and is run as any other
>   scheduled process, the information it displays can never be exact.

I know of other ways such as using `ps_util` in python and retrieve the information that way. However, is this (and any other tool) faster or more reliable? If so, can you recommend a tool? 
Or is the `ps` command safe enough?

Answer (score 0):

`ps` is primarily a snapshot tool that gives you an instant view of at that given moment. You cannot get instant CPU percentage from `ps`. The `ps` page gives out this information regarding CPU:

> CPU usage is currently expressed as the percentage of time spent
>   running during the entire lifetime of a process.  This is not ideal,
>   and it does not conform to the standards that ps otherwise conforms
>   to.  CPU usage is unlikely to add up to exactly 100%.

You can use the tool `top` which is a monitoring tool that keeps polling for numbers over time. I'd recommend using `top` as it for cases where you want repetitive updates.

For a more detailed explanation on differences between `top` and `ps`, you can read the answers on this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58539/top-and-ps-not-showing-the-same-cpu-result

Comment: Thanks for your help.